SUM values in a column but show all the rows after group by
I have the below Table



NAME
VAL
ID
SIG




DOE
4000
1
0


DOE
5000
8
0


JON
8000
9
1


JON
5000
9
0


DOE
1000
4
0



I need to group by columns  NAME and SIG and create another column SUMVAL whose SUM is obtained by a Group of NAME and SIG values as in the above example we have three rows with the Name DOE and SIG value as 0
so after initial grouping the output will be below , DOE will have one record and JON will have two records having two SIG Values



NAME
SUMVAL
SIG




DOE
10000
0


JON
8000
1


JON
5000
0



I was able to get the above output , but however I want the below output, where I need to get the SUMVAL spread for other rows too and show the complete view with all the records



NAME
SUMVAL
ID
SIG




DOE
10000
1
0


DOE
10000
8
0


JON
8000
9
1


JON
5000
9
0


DOE
10000
4
0



I tried the below command and half way through, but couldn't get the rest working
select sum(VAL) as SUMVAL,ID
GROUP BY SIG,NAME 


How do I get all the rows back again like in the above output ?


Your expected output does not make sense or match the initial data.  Please correct this.

Please explain why SUMVAL is 1000 for DOE in all 3 rows of the desired output.. show exact calculation steps with explanations. Maybe you need not 1000 but 10000 instead?

correct @Akina corrected the expected output above

Note: The proper way to deal with closed questions is to edit them according to the comments and information to have them reopened, rather than deleting it and ask it again. Please do that next time!

What is your MySQL version precisely?

Since you want all the rows back, and there is special column id, so I say you should not use group by at all.
Try this, I think you should use sub queries
select 
name, 
(select sum(val) from your_table as i where i.name = o.name and i.sig=o.sig) as sumval, 
id, 
sig 
from your_table as o;


The GROUP BY statement should list the non-aggregated column in the SELECT.
Looks like you want to group over NAME and SIG so the query to do that would be:
select NAME, sum(val), SIG
from data
group by NAME, SIG

See a dbfiddle

For MySQL 8+ use window version of SUM():
SELECT name, SUM(val) OVER (PARTITION BY name, sig) sumval, id, sig
FROM test;




name
sumval
id
sig




DOE
10000
1
0


DOE
10000
8
0


DOE
10000
4
0


JON
5000
9
0


JON
8000
9
1



fiddle
